# NLP - Find which Verb is talking about the Noun in a sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Given a sentence, Using python NLTK how can I know which Verb is talking about which Noun.

Eg: Cat sat on the mat.
Here "sat(verb)" is talking about "Cat(noun)".

*Consider a complex sentence which has more nouns & verbs*
Thank You.

Comment: This is much too broad. You need anaphora resolution and a fair amount of semantics / pragmatics to *really* solve this.

Comment: First you need a syntactic analysis at all: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html could be a start. But your question is really too broad.

Comment: You don't need "anaphora resolution", in fact it wouldn't help you here. You need to know about the structure of the sentence: The cat is the subject-- is that what you mean by "talking about"? More generally, read up on syntactic concepts a bit if you need to do more than just answer this particular question. Then look up "dependency parser" in the NLTK book (and elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

That's a good suggestion, I will try it with anaphora too.

For now, my problem is solved by the concept of noun phrase & verb phrase.

1. I extracted clause(s) from the sentence
2. identified verbs & nouns in each, and
3. related them through an iterative technique.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Good luck. But you really should ask and answer much more specific.